# Make a Sass mixin that writes part of the CSS into a different CSS file

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

I've created a Sass mixin which generates `font-sizes` in `rem` with a `px` fallback for IE and below. However for the sake of niceness, I was wondering whether there is a way for me (most likely through the `config.rb` file) to move any `css` rule prefixed with a `class` ( `.lte8` ) to a different CSS file ( `ie-fixes.css` )?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to do this at the moment. It is a highly sought after feature, but it is also highly controversial. You can read a lengthy discussion on the matter here: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/241

There are also tools to conditionally print styles, one of which can be found here: https://github.com/Team-Sass/jacket

Comment: Thanks for the links, the first is a good read. I'm not necessarily wanting sass to do the work though. I'm quite happy for some ruby function to come along and strip chunks of CSS from my compiled CSS file and move it to another, if that's possible (I have close to zero experience with ruby)